# Were people of Srimad Ramayana period aware of Surgery?

Tags: ramayana, sita

People in Ramayana era knew about surgery.  Go through the following narration.

Seetha recollects the time limit of two months given by Ravana and her vulnerability of being killed by him. Seetha, tormented by grief, lamented as follows.

> नूनं ममाङ्गान्यचिरादनार्यः |
> शस्त्रैः शितै श्छेत्स्यति राक्षसेन्द्रः |
> तस्मिन्ननागच्छति लोकनाथे |
> गर्भस्थजन्तोरिव शल्यकृन्तः ||
>
> (Sundara Kanda 28 Sarga 6th Sloka)
>
> "If Sri Rama does not come here, the evil Ravana will cut off my limbs with his sharpened weapons, even as a surgeon would cut the limbs of a lifeless feotus."

Seeta’s saying that Ravana would cut off her limbs with his sharpened weapons  as a surgeon would cut the limbs of a lifeless fetus indicate that the people at the period of Ramayana knew about surgery.

Am I right?